# Ruby (Rack) application could not be started - mysql library error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

Bluehost just upgraded their MySql version and broke my application.
I now get "Ruby (Rack) application could not be started" and this specific file load error:

```
libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home4/mychairs/ruby/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
```

Notice the super long root-based path.
Running

```
bundle install
```

via SSH and then

```
bundle show mysql2
```

I am told that I am using this library:

```
/home4/mychairs/ruby/gems/gems/mysql2-0.3.11
```

I cannot tell where the abnormal path is being generated.

Comment: Abnormal path? Looks like it's just the path to the lib.

Comment: The file is present where the path leads and yet it won't load. I checked permissions: 755 on the mysql2.so file. My conclusion is that the root section of the path must be odd. I cannot traverse upwards past "/ruby" so I cannot verify.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the mysql gem manually and reinstall it via 'bundle install'.  Bundler has no idea the underlying MySQL lib has changed, it just knows that the gem is there.